# Issue while linking testlink with selenium

Tags: selenium, testlink

Please help me out, while executing the code I am getting an error

> testlink.api.java.client.TestLinkAPIException: The test case
>   identifier null was not found and the test case 485 could not be
>   accessed to report a test result to test plan UIAutomatoion.

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: reference Code 

http://www.software-testing-tutorials-automation.com/2016/06/automate-testlink-test-case-result.html